# How are OS configuration changes controlled when using Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

When using Azure web/worker roles users can specify `osVersion` to explicitly set ["Guest OS image" version](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix/). This ensures that when Microsoft issues new critical updates they are first shown up on a newer "OS image" which users can explicitly specify and test their service on.

How is the same achieved with Azure Service Fabric? Suppose I deployed my service into Azure Service Fabric and it's been running for a month, then Microsoft issues updates for the OS on the server where the service is running - how are they applied such that I can test them first to ensure they don't break the service?

Comment: Today you do not have that option. The image based patching capability is work in progress. I posted a road map to get there on the team blog : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/01/09/os-patching-for-vms-running-service-fabric/  Try out the script and report any issues you hit. Looking forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brett is correct. SF cluster is based on Azure VMSS and the expectation is that the customer is responsible to patch the OS. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade/

We have heard from majority of the SF customers that this is not at all desirable and that they do not want to be responsible for OS patching.

The feature to enable an OPT-IN automatic OS patching is indeed a very high priority within Azure Compute team. The exact details on how best to offer this is still in design, however the intent is to have this functionality enabled   before the end of the year.

Although that is the right long term solution, to mitigate this issue in the short term, SF team is working on a set of steps that will enable the customers to opt into  having the their VMs patched using WU in a safe manner.  Once the steps are tested out, we will blog about it and will publish a document detailing the steps. Expect that in the next couple of months.

Comment: Will that work like "Guest OS images" or will it be like "whatever, patch and I don't care if it breaks"?

Comment: The long term solution will be similar to the Azure cloud services "Guest OS patching" that is based on OS images.

Comment: @chacko-MSFT has there been any progress on either documenting the process for the short term or the feature?

Comment: Yes, The automatic VM Image based OS patching (similar to Azure Cloud Services ) is planned for CYQ2/2017 and will be a part of the VMSS model. Till then, for supporting SF customers, we will have a service that can be deployed to the cluster to made the OS patching safe. This service is expected to land in Feb/2017.  The Manual script to safely roll out the OS patches is expected to be released by Dec/15th. We are currently testing it. Sorry about the delays on this.

Comment: Looks like the script and instructions were released a few days ago, and there are a couple more details on the future state here [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/01/09/os-patching-for-vms-running-service-fabric/)

Comment: Yes, we released a  manually initiated script that the cluster administrator can run to gracefully patch a service fabric cluster. That and the future road map to get to the image based patching is also mentioned on the service fabric team blog : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/01/09/os-patching-for-vms-running-service-fabric/

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it you are currently responsible for managing patching on SF cluster nodes yourself. Apparently moving this to be a SF managed feature is planned but I have no idea how far down the road it might be.

I personally would make this a high priority. Having used Cloud Services for many years I have come to rely on never having to patch my VM's manually. SF is a large backwards step in this particular area.

It'd be great to hear from an Azure PM on this...

Answer (score 1):

Automatic Image based patching like cloud services in service fabric.

Today you do not have that option. The image based patching capability is work in progress. I posted a road map to get there on the team blog : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/01/09/os-patching-for-vms-running-service-fabric/  Try out the script and report any issues you hit. Looking forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of parts of Service Fabric are huge rolling dumpster fires backwards. Whole new hosts of problems have been introduced that the IIS/WAS/WCF team have already solved that need to be developed for once again. The concept of releasing a PAAS platform while requiring OS patch management is laughable. To add insult to injury there is no migration path from "classic cloud PAAS" to this stuff. WEEEE I get to write my very own service host. Something that was provided out of the box for a decade by WAS. Not all of us were scared by the ability to control all aspects of service host communication options via configuration. Now we get to use code so a tweak channel configuration requires a full patch/release cycle!